# What could make GDB refuse to break?

Tags: c, gdb

I'm at a loss here. I'm writing a compiler in C (for hobby), and compiling with GCC 4.6.1 on amd64 Linux 2.6.32, using GDB 7.3. Flags are "-Wall -Wextra -O0 -g", in addition to the usual -I and whatnot. I have a function whose purpose is to report a parse error, defined as follows:

```
void cerror_at (struct lex *lex, struct token *tok, const char *fmt, ...)
```

Other than being variadic, nothing weird. The problem is that GDB will NOT break at it. I've tried every way I can think of (breakpoint at the function, inside the function, before it's called, you name it), but as soon as my program is inside the function, I get messages like "warning: Error removing breakpoint 0" and GDB just lets the program finish. There's nothing wrong with it any more (I've since fixed the bug I was trying to find, and everything runs as it should), but I can't get into the function. Any ideas on what could cause this?

**Edit:** More information! GDB is setting the breakpoint at 0x403057. The function starts at 0x403025. Look at this part of the disassembly:

```
0x0000000000403053 <+46>:   test   %al,%al
0x0000000000403055 <+48>:   je     0x403077 <cerror_at+82>
```

At this point, it skips ahead to 0x403077 (past the breakpoint). I've verified that placing the breakpoint at an address before the "je" works, as well as at an address at or after 0x403077, the target of the jump, but not in between (where GDB is trying to place it). Why would GDB place the breakpoint in the middle of the function? Even GDB tells me that the function's address is, in fact, 0x403025.

Comment: Just a couple thoughts that you've probably considered already: Is the code actually being executed, and is the breakpoint on an executable statement?

Comment: Yes, the code is definitely being executed; I can see the error message it prints out. The breakpoints outside the function are either right on the call itself, which is definitely executable, or on the function call before it that discovers the error condition. The breakpoint inside the function gets placed on an fprintf().

Comment: More info - I just tried getting into the function using 'si', one instruction at a time. It actually does go in, but the line numbers it reports jump around, it seems to have no clue what it's doing, and then it gives me the same "Error removing breakpoint" message at the end of the function.

Comment: Have you verified that a symbol for `cerror_at` is actually getting omitted in the compiled object file?  Have you tried stepping through the disassembly to verify that the function is actually getting called (and not, say, an inlined version of it)?  Have you tried setting a breakpoint at a specific virtual address within the function's disassembly?

Comment: Actually, a symbol for cerror_at is not getting omitted. The function itself is definitely getting called, and setting a breakpoint at a specific address (thank you, I didn't think of that) gives the same odd behavior as using 'si'

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say *emitted*, not *omitted*.  Does running the command line `nm the_executable` (in your shell, not in gdb) list `cerror_at` as a symbol?  Does gdb print out the correct address if you run `print cerror_at` at the gdb prompt?  Is it the same address you get when you step through the disassembly with `si`?

Comment: Have you tried `-ggdb` instead of `-g`?

Comment: Yes, nm lists cerror_at, and the address matches what GDB reports. And no, I hadn't tried -ggdb, but I just did and it doesn't help.

Comment: Is it possible the function is being inlined?  I know you said you compiled with -O0, but most of these symptoms (breakpoint not triggered, `si` showing line numbers jumping around randomly) are consistent with a function that has been inlined...

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is your program using multiple threads?

Comment: No inlining - a disassembly confirms a "callq" to the true address of the function at that point - and no, just a single thread.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm just dense, but the most common reasons I've come across for a debugger to refuse to break are the most simple ones.

1. The code that I'm trying to debug doesn't exactly match the code in the debugger.
2. I forgot to compile that library with debugging options.

Be sure you check both of these anytime you get a debugging error like this, even if you think it's not the problem.

Comment: Yes, I've checked both. All the code is up to date and correct, I'm in the right file, GDB is operating on the right file, and a verbose compile confirms that everything is getting the "-g" option.

Comment: Also try completely rebuilding all object files and executable. Not a common problem to have a bad build like this, but worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bug in GDB. In particular, `Error removing breakpoint 0` is very suspicious (it's a breakpoint GDB automatically inserted somewhere; user-inserted breakpoints have positive numbers).

You should probably try to create a reduced test case and file a bug [here](http://www.sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi).

Comment: Honestly, that hadn't occurred to me, which is dumb considering I've dealt with a GDB bug before. And even if it's not a GDB bug, trying to reduce this problem to its essence would probably help me figure out what the problem is. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should try to understand what machine code was generated by the compile:

in GDB, you can see the actual function code with `disassemble cerror_at`
which should give something like (x86_64):

```
(gdb) disassemble dive
Dump of assembler code for function dive:
   0x0000000000400504 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400505 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400508 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000000000040050c <+8>: mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000040050f <+11>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
   0x0000000000400512 <+14>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x0000000000400515 <+17>:    mov    %eax,%edi
   0x0000000000400517 <+19>:    callq  0x400504 <dive>
   0x000000000040051c <+24>:    leaveq
   0x000000000040051d <+25>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

Then check that the subroutine is actually called: break the execution a few instruction before your function call, then:

```
   (gdb) x/5i $p
=> 0x400539 <main+27>:  mov    $0x1,%esi
   0x40053e <main+32>:  mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x400541 <main+35>:  callq  0x400408 <fwrite@plt>
   0x400546 <main+40>:  mov    $0x1,%edi
-->0x40054b <main+45>:  callq  0x400504 <dive> <------
```

the output should be slightly different with another CPU architecture, but you should be able see a branching instruction pointing to the address of your function.

--

And you can execute `maint info breakpoint` just *before* the moment where you see `Error removing breakpoint 0`to know where the `breakpoint 0` was set, it might help to understand what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your latest edit, I bet this is a compiler bug.  Specifically, I bet there is a problem with the generation of DWARF debugging information, which is what GDB uses to map between addresses in the object code and files/procedures/line numbers in the source.

You might try experimenting with `-gdwarf-4`, `-gdwarf-3`, or even `-gdwarf-2` to see if it makes any difference.

If you can reduce this to a simple test case, I suspect the gcc developers would accept it as a bug.

Of course, this could also be a bug in GDB.  But given this behavior, I think that is less likely.