# GDB cannot tell different source files when compiling them within #include？

Tags: c, gdb

Just a small program of stdarg.h, when I organizing source file in a single source file as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void
print(const char *, ...);
void
print(const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list vlist;
  va_start(vlist, format);
  vfprintf(stdout, format, vlist);
  va_end(vlist);
  return;
}

int 
main（int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *message = "Just a test";

  print("==> %s <==\n", message);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The below code in a single file works well under gdb when debugging, it stopped where I expected.
But when I organizing the code in 3 files: print.c main.c test.c

```
/* print.c */
void
print(const char *, ...);
void
print(const char *format, ...)
{
  va_list vlist;
  va_start(vlist, format);
  vfprintf(stdout, format, vlist);
  va_end(vlist);
  return;
}
/* main.c */
int 
main（int argc, char **argv)
{
  const char *message = "Just a test";

  print("==> %s <==\n", message);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
/* test.c */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "print.c"
#include "main.c"
```

I use command `gcc -g test.c`, and run it under linux. When breaking at print, it refused to break and continue to run to the end, within a warning "error removing breakpoint 0".

I suppose that maybe it related to stdarg.h, because I am always organizing code in that way, but the first time met the problem.

Comment: 1. Are you sure you remembered to recompile? 2. Don't include .c files

Comment: Yes. I am sure I cleaned all the intermediate files, and rebuilt the source files. It works well when there is no va_list, but this time, gdb refuse to break. otherwise it exits normally.

Comment: What is `SUCCESS_EXIT`? This can't possibly be your real code.

Comment: I am sorry that I just type it for this is very short.

Comment: gdb breaks just fine for me.

Comment: in this way "gcc -g test.c"?

Comment: Yes, just like that, then `gdb ./a.out`, `list`, `break 6`, and `run`. Even though it works, `#include`ing `.c` files is still a terrible practice.

Comment: I tried it again on my machine, and failed. My OS is ubuntu 12.04 with 7.4-2012.04 version gdb.

Comment: It's possible you have a buggy version, here's [a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493601/what-could-make-gdb-refuse-to-break).

Comment: Thanks. I see this. In here, It works well in other situations. But this include stdarg.h, it failed.

Comment: I have another question that why including .c files is a terrible practice? THANKS.

Comment: There's a pretty good explanation why to avoid it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232693/including-one-c-source-file-in-another . It also explains why it may be good, but that's mostly obsolete reasons as compilers are better now